# t-distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a question regarding non standardized t-distribution in python. I have the location, degrees of freedom and scale parameters for which I use the notation `a`, `b` and `c` respectively. What I want to do is sample from the non standardized t-distribution with these parameters.

I found this online [`scipy.stats.t`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html) about the parameters that python uses to formulate the non stantardized t distribution.

Is it correct to use `stats.t.rvs(a, b, c)` to sample from this distribution?

Comment: Those docs say `rvs(df, loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)`, so with `df` the degrees of freedom, you should b, a, and c as the order. Or just explicitly use the parameter names: `fvs(df=b, loc=a, scale=1, ...)`, which makes life a lot clearer (a, b and c are unclear and rather generic variable names. I advise you to rename those to better suited names such as loc, dof or df, and scale).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in your link, the format for `scipy.stat.t.rvs` is:

> rvs(df, loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)

without that explicit designator, the inputs are asigned based on order specified in the function definition (with anything omitted replaced by the default value)

So in this case the correct order for sampling would be:

```
stats.t.rvs(b, a, c)
```

This sets `loc = a`, `df = b`, `scale = c`, `size = 1` (the default) and `random_state = None` (also default)

You can also explicitly set the variables to the arguments of the function, in any order

```
stats.t.rvs(loc = a, df = b, scale = c)
```

which has the same result as above.

as @Everts suggested, it is much easier to verify that the parameters are correct if the variable names match, so:

```
df = b
loc = a
scale = c

stats.t.rvs(df = df, loc = loc, scale = scale)
```

is the *clearest* method that will keep you from being tripped up.